# python TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'namespace'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to initialize class using

`tsf = TimeSeriesFeature(cut_avg, interval)`

but I got TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'namespace'.

The init code of TimeSeriesFeature is below:

```
class TimeSeriesFeature(BasicFeature):
    def __init__(self, cut_avg, interval):
        super().__init__()
        self.cut_avg = cut_avg
        self.interval = interval
        self.get_avg()
```

and BasicFeature init code:

```
class BasicFeature(ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.times = {}
        self.avg = {}
```

and I'm using python3.5. Is there any mistake?

Comment: Why do you inherit from `ABCMeta`? It's a metaclass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you're getting is from the fact that instantiation of metaclass does not use it's `__init__` method, but rather it's `__new__` method which (excluding self) expects 3 arguments, last being said *namespace*.

As it stands now your class inherits from `ABCMeta` (which is [a metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta)), therefore it is also a metaclass:

```
class BasicFeature(ABCMeta):
    ...
```

but I think you'd rather set `ABCMeta` as a metaclass of your class:

```
class BasicFeature(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    ...
```

That way your class becomes an ordinary class, with `ABCMeta` as it's metaclass.

If you'd like `BasicFeature` to be a abstract (in other words impossible to initialize) class, add an abstract method to it, like this:

```
class BasicFeature(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def get_avg():
        pass
```

and overload it in subclass without the `@abstractmethod` decorator:

```
class TimeSeriesFeature(BasicFeature):

    def get_avg():
        # ... some code
        # ... some code
```

Then, users who attempt to instantiate `BasicFeature` will get an error about `get_avg()` being abstract, but users who instantiate `TimeSeriesFeature` will not. More details available in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod)

Comment: I don't want others to initialize BasicFeature, so I inherit from ABCMeta. So is there any good way to prevent it?

Comment: I've extended my answer to also address question in your comment. Without more extensive code sample I don't know what method would be a good candidate to be the `@abstractmethod`, but I hope that the example above is clear.